# Cannot find the gem "Could not find aws-sigv4-1.0.0 in any of the sources"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

```
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'dotenv'
gem 'sinatra'
```

This is my gem file. But when i use bundle install i see this output.

```
root@DESKTOP-ETLLRI1 C:\Users\root\Desktop\case 9\FaceRekognition-Demo
$ bundle install
Resolving dependencies...
Your Gemfile has no gem server sources. If you need gems that are not already on
your machine, add a line like this to your Gemfile:
source 'https://rubygems.org'
Could not find aws-sigv4-1.0.0 in any of the sources
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add this line at the beginning of your Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#Step 1 
gem install aws-sigv4 -v 1.0.3
#Step 2
bundle update
```